# How to arrange tensorboard's graphs horizontally in tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using the following code, the drawing is arranged vertically, how to change it to horizontal arrangement?

```
with self.summary_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", self.loss[-1], step=self.steps)
    tf.summary.scalar("reward", self.rewards[-1], step=self.steps)
    tf.summary.scalar("average_rewards", np.nanmean(self.rewards[-1000:]), step=self.steps)
```

I didn't find it in the homepage of tensorflow.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar

[image: picture]

Comment: You should ask a new question and not edit your original question after it was solved. Think about other people coming across this problem..

Comment: Yes，I commited a new question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex expressions as suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/836) to align your plots:

```
import tensorflow as tf

logdir = 'logs/func/'
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", 5, step=0)
    tf.summary.scalar("reward", 6, step=1)
    tf.summary.scalar("average_rewards", 7, step=2)
```

Start tensorboard:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir logs/func
```

< Click on image to see more details>
[image]

Comment: Thanks, from your link I found that changing the name to something like 'status/action' worked. However, how to change the name on the tag to something like 'action'?

Comment: See my top picture.I saw that in some pytorch demos, the pictures can be like that.

Comment: @jaried but that was not your question.. you wanted to know how to horizontally align the plots.. or did I not understand you correctly?

Comment: OK, let me resubmit a question.